# How to pass attribute of one model as a param to a different model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameter-passing, parameters

I have a `Favorite` model and an `Article` model. The `Favorite` has an attribute `fav_id` that is equal to the the `id` of `Article`. 
I want to create a link_to `@article.title` and pass a param of `:id=>@favorite.fav_id`.

`favorites` controller code:

```
def show
  @favorite = Favorite.find(params[:id])
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

`view/favorite/show` code:

```
<%= link_to @article.title, article_path(:controller=>:article, :id=>@favorite.fav_id, :action=>'view')
```

When I load the page, the `favorite` id is used, which is fine. I just want to pass `favorite.fav_id` to the `@article = Article.find(params[:id])`. That way, the link will show the article title instead of a number (`fav_id`). In the future id like to be able to show `@article.description` and other attributes too.

I have also considered passing the article attributes to favorite, but this seems like itd be a heavier load on the database so I've so far avoided that

I've also tried a `:through => association`. Maybe I did it wrong, but `:through` didn't work when I tried it. Any suggestions?

Rails 4.2.0
Ruby 2.1.5

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, normally you would use an [ActiveRecord association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for this, but you can pass whatever you want to Article.find. You say you want to pass `favorite.fav_id`  to Article.find -- have you tried simply doing so? `Article.find(@favorite.fav_id)`.  But again, this is not normally the way one would do this in ActiveRecord. Yes, normally you would use an association ("through" is needed only if the association is many-to-many, if one favorite can have many articles, which i think it probably can't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Favorite` model has an attribute, pointing to another model (`Article`), that means, by definition, that there's an `association` between those models. So you should explicitely set that association in your models.

First of all you need to define the `association type`. In your case it an be either a `has_one` association in case an `article` may correnpond to only one `favorite` or a `has_many` association if one `article` may correspond to multiple `favorits` (multiple favourities can have the save `fav_id`).

Then you need to set up your association in both the `Article` and the `Favorite` models.

In your `app/models/article.rb` it will go like this:

```
has_one :favorite, foreign_key: :fav_id
```

In your `app/models/favorite.rb` it will go like this:

```
belongs_to :article, foreign_key: :fav_id
```

I recommend you though to simplify that by changing the field name from `fav_id` to `article_id` so that you can drop the `foreign_key` parameter in both definitions.

Make sure to read [the API docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more information on working with associations.

After you set up that association, you can easily use it in the controller.

```
def show 
   @favorite = Favorite.find params[:id]
   @article = @favorite.article
end
```

And then just use `link_to @article.title, @article` in your view.

Comment: Awesome, that worked! Thanks so much, I realized that I had it backwords with article.rb using belongs_to and vice versa.

Comment: How to show the title of model B item in the index (listing) page of model A items? A (always) has_one B.. Any information would be highly valuable.

Answer (score 0):

I cant clearly understand what you are going to get, but this:
`

```
def show
  @favorite = Favorite.find(params[:id])
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

Is completely wrong. You are trying to use same `:id` parameter to find either Article and Favorite. I don`t think this is behavior you are waiting for.

> The Favorite has an attribute of .fav_id

Also, why Favorite model has `fav_id` attribute? Is it Single Table Inheritance? Or what? Rails way would be, for example, Favorite to have `article_id`.

Comment: yes .fav_id is the same as .article_id. My naming was confusing